# error in lfs installation in python "no module named lfs_theme

Tags: python, payment-gateway

I am following an installation in lfs to insert a check out page in my website. I have copies all the instruction but after I tried to mia it produces an error.

```
   (my_project) PS C:\my_project\src> python manage.py migrate
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "C:\my_project\lib\site-
   packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in 
   execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
   File "C:\my_project\lib\site-
   packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
   django.setup()
   File "C:\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in 
   setup
   apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "C:\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, 
   in populate
   app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
   File "C:\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in 
   create
   module = import_module(entry)
   File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
   __import__(name)
   ImportError: No module named lfs_theme
  (my_project) PS C:\my_project\src>
```